# R - Vector and operation with its element

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector as

```
x <- c(1:10).
```

then I have code like below

```
(x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))
```

The above returns a vector again. So my understanding is: in R if I use Vector of values then the operation I involve with `x` is applicable to all its values. So this:

```
x - 1
```

Will return a vector of `x`'s elements subtracted by `1`. Am I right?

If that's the case then this should work for other data structures like `data`, `frame` and `list`.

Comment: I don't understand how you come to the conclusion in your last sentence. Why do you assume that what works for one data structure should work for a different data structure?

Answer (score 0):

What you say is true for vectors, but not for lists and data.frames (note that data.frames are a special type of list).

I've put a demonstration below of what I think you are trying to get at:

```
# test as vector
x <- c(1:10)
x - 1


# test as list
x <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
x - 1

# approperiate way to apply function to list
lapply(x, function(x) x - 1)
```

You can see what while I can easily subtract 1 from the vector x, this fails on the list (and will also fail on the data.frame). The reason for this is that you have to specify which element of the list/data.frame you would like to perform the function on, or use lapply in order to apply the function to every element of the list/data.frame.

Part of the reason for this is that elements of data.frames and lists can contain vectors, data.frames, and lists themselves. So you need to be clear about what you want to apply your function to. A further example:

```
#list that contains vector as first and second elements
x <- list(c(1:10),c(1:10))

#apply function to both vectors in the list
x[[1]]-1
lapply(x, function(x) x - 1)
```

Hopefully that gives you something to start with.